# DAX Calculate how many months each customers active in one year

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image: Total months of each customers active in 1 year]

How can I get the total months of each customers active in 1 year.

Active = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Sales-table'[customer] ), 'Sales-table'[sales] > 0)

return as table but I couldn't SUM after DAX return the result, Could you please advise?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your models, relationships, and attributes? Also please specify (1) expected outcome value for each customer and (2) expected Grand Total outcome value and (3) expected Column Sub-Total outcome value.